# matlab equal does not work

Tags: matlab, math-software

[image: How to judge whether two whatever is equal? alphat and alpha are two kind big vectors. Why it turns 0, which means they are not equal?]

How to judge whether two whatever is equal? alphat and alpha are two kind big vectors. Why it turns 0, which means they are not equal?

Comment: i'd suspect this is because the two numbers are computed with more precision than what matlab is showing in the output, and they differ at some place. it's my understanding that checking if two floats are literally equal is generally a bad idea, you should check if they are the same up to some tolerance

Comment: If you enter the command  ">> format long"  then Matlab will give you a lot more digits for each number

Answer (score 5):

Floating point numbers are notoriously difficult to compare with `eq()`, `==` or any other direct bitwise comparison. This is because finite precision arithmetic rarely allows us to compute exact values. If two different algorithms compute the same result differently, it is nearly guaranteed that the numerical result will differ by some small amount.

Your best bet is to do an "almost equals" comparison:

```
epsilon = 1e-8; % Or some other suitably small number
if abs(alphat(16108)-alpha(16108)) < epsilon
.... % equality is met
end
```